# Does purging cache on cloudflare also purge cache on browser?

Tags: node.js, caching, express, browser-cache, cloudflare

I have deployed my node app on heroku and I have cloudflare as CDN infront of it. Now my question is, if  there are changes to my javascript and if I purge the cache in cloudflare, will this automatically purge the browser cache? 
I have following setting in my expressjs server file

```
if ('production' == process.env.NODE_ENV) {  //production
    var oneYear = 31557600000;
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge: oneYear}));
} else { //development
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
```

If the purge on cloudflare doesnt purge browser cache, then what is the best strategy to purge browser cache every time I change my javascript or css files?

Regards,
Chidan

Comment: Guys, please help me here.  What if I set the maxAge to 1 ms hence browser will always check back to see if there is a new content. Will this expire the cache at cloudflare? If yes, then cloudflare will provide newcontent. If no, then there is no change in content hence there will be no swap of cache. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best approach:

1. Use node's fs module to read all static files every time the server is reloaded (or setTimeout periodically)
2. Read each file and use crypto module to make an md5 hash of the file
3. Compare the hash with the last stored hash and store the new hash (use any kind of permanent storage like Mongo, MySQL, or even another disk files (I use the files method because it doesn't mess up with app logic, my script maintains the md5 sums in the same-named file in same location, only the '.md5cache.' prefix is added)
4. Append the hash as a query string to your filepaths in  section of your web template.

If the hash didn't change, browser sees the same filename and loads it from cache. If there's a different hash attached as a a query string in the name, browser will query the server for the new version.

Cloudflare has an option to disable ignoring behavior of query strings, so just disable that and you're good to go.

I am aware of eTags solution but I've never managed to get it working properly. I don't think node is capable of working with eTags very well but I could be wrong. It's not my concern now as I find my method very well designed and I use it as a library in every project I ever do.

Answer (score -1):

You still probably want to do a hard refresh on the browser because of browser caching.

Comment: But How do I do it programatically, obviously I cannot control user behavior and ask users to do a hard refresh, there has to be some way to tell the cache has expired and the browser has to download new cache.

Comment: What if I set the maxAge to 1 ms hence browser will always check back to see if there is a new content. Will this expire the cache at cloudflare? If yes, then cloudflare will provide newcontent. If no, then there is no change in content hence there will be no swap of cache. Is my assumption correct? –